# how to call function to pointer of a class?

Tags: c++

```
class A;
class B;

class B
{
public:
    void fn1(void (A::*fn)() )
    {

       //(*A::fn) ();how to call fn()?
    }
};


class A
{
    B *b;
public:
    A():b(new B){}
    void fn2()
    {
        cout<<"fn2"<<endl;
    }
    void fn3()
    {
        b->fn1(&A::fn2);
    }

};


int main()
{
    A a;
    a.fn3();
}
```

I was asked this question in an interview: how to call fn2() from fn1(). That is what I am trying to solve. Can someone help me with that?
My main objective is to call fn2() from fn1(); if any other way is possible, please mention that

Comment: You need an `A` to call `A::*fn`. Which `A` object should it be called on? `a`?

Comment: Perhaps they were looking for the answer  "given that code, you can't" so they could continue with "why not, and what changes would you suggest?"

Comment: @molbdnilo Personally I'd offer up both parts of that answer in one go. Just saying "you can't" isn't an impressive interview answer! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pointers-to-member-functions need an object to call the function on.

The quickest change to your code is to simply pass in a pointer to the object you want to use. I assume that's the `A` that you called `fn3` on.

So:

```
void fn1(void (A::*fn)(), A* ptr)
{
   (ptr->*fn)();   // Yeah, the syntax is kind of weird
}
```

and:

```
void fn3()
{
    b->fn1(&A::fn2, this);
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02d722af9bf6cb96))

In an interview I'd give this solution, then discuss how in modern C++ we'd prefer to have `fn1` take a `std::function` (or a template callable), and bind the argument using `std::bind` or pass a lambda.

Comment: So, in this example, why bother to pass `&A::fn2` at all?  Why not just call `ptr->fn2();`?

Comment: in that case I am getting error; error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class A’
        ptr->fn2();
If I declare B after A; still I get incomplete type B

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy Presumably it's a minimal working example. Of course in this contrived example you could just invoke it directly.

Comment: @user1434287 To your original code, I only made the changes described, and I provided a live demo showing that it works. You must have changed something?